# Dates in R calculating number of days

Tags: r

I'm having data as

```
customer_id Last_city    First city       recent_date
1020         Jaipur       Gujarat         20130216
1021         Delhi        Lucknow         20130129
1022         Mumbai       Punjab          20130221
```

and I want to find the number of days from recent date and today (for every record).

Comment: `Sys.Date() - as.Date(as.character(df$recent_date), format = "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: `library(lubridate); as.integer(today() - ymd(df[["recent_date"]]))`

Comment: Hi,Sys.Date() - as.Date(as.character(df$recent_date), format = "%Y%m%d") This code is showing a message only "TIME DIFFERENCE OF DAYS"........ where the code library(lubridate); as.integer(today() - ymd(df[["recent_date"]])) is showing an ERROR message "Format failed to parse"

Answer (score 0):

[difftime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html) function calculates time difference in days, hours, minutes, etc.
First, need to parse the date string into a date representation (e.g. [Date](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/as.Date) or [POSIXct](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html)) then compare that to the current date/time.

```
# create dummy data.frame for testing
df <- data.frame("customer_id"=1020, "Last_city"="Jaipur",
    "First_city"="Gujarat", "recent_date"="20130216",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

now <- Sys.Date()
# parse date into date type (Note: %Y=4-digit year, %y=2-digit year)
df$date = as.Date(df$recent_date, format = "%Y%m%d") 
# next calculate the difference between recent date and current time
df$diff = as.double(difftime(now, df$date, units = c("days")))

> df
  customer_id Last_city First_city recent_date       date  diff
1        1020    Jaipur    Gujarat    20130216 2013-02-16  1604
```

If wanted the difference in weeks then

```
>  as.double(difftime(now, df$date, units = c("weeks")))
[1] 229.1429
```